# How to filter characters from a string with C++/Boost

Tags: c++, string, boost

This seems like such a basic question, so I apologize if it's already been answered somewhere (my searching didn't turn up anything).

I just want to filter a string object so that it contains only alphanumeric and space characters.

Here's what I tried:

```
#include "boost/algorithm/string/erase.hpp"
#include "boost/algorithm/string/classification.hpp"

std::wstring oldStr = "Bla=bla =&*\nSampleSampleSample ";
std::wstring newStr = boost::erase_all_copy(oldStr, !(boost::is_alnum() || 
                                                      boost::is_space()));
```

But the compiler is not at all happy with that -- it seems that I can only put a string in the second argument of `erase_all_copy` and not this `is_alnum()` stuff.

Is there some obvious solution I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the std algorithms and Boost.Bind:

```
std::wstring s = ...
std::wstring new_s;
std::locale loc;
std::remove_copy_if(s.begin(), s.end(), std::back_inserter(new_s), 
    !(boost::bind(&std::isalnum<wchar_t>, _1, loc)||
      boost::bind(&std::isspace<wchar_t>, _1, loc)
));
```

Comment: That worked, thank you!  At this point, it all just looks like black magic to me, but it'll give me a place to start understanding iterators and the C++ way of things better.

Comment: @jjiffer: remove_copy_if takes an input range (the "s.begin(), s.end()" part) and an output iterator to which it writes the extracted characters (the "back_inserter(new_s)" part). The fourth argument is a function object that takes an element as input (in this case a wchar_t) and returns bool. If this function returns true, the element is skipped.
(to be continued....)

Comment: This function object is created here with boost::bind. "bind(&isalnum, _1, loc)" returns a function object that stores a pointer to the isalnum function and a copy of "loc". That function object, when invoked with one argument will in turn call isalnum(the_argument, loc) and return its result. Finally, operator overloading magic allows us to combine two function objects created with bind with the OR operator, and to negate its result with the NOT operator.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I had no clue C++ had anything like bind.  Thanks for explanation!

Answer (score 1):

It's been years since I've used boost, but perhaps you could use [erase_all_regex_copy()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/erase_all_regex_copy.html) instead of erase_all_copy()? It might be a bit of a performance hit, but it may be your only choice aside from iterating over each element and checking manually. If you're not familiar with regular expressions, the expression you'd use in this case would be something like  "[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+".

For completeness' sake, some sample code:

```
#include "boost/regex.hpp"
#include "boost/algorithm/string/regex.hpp"

std::wstring oldStr = "Bla=bla =&*\nSampleSampleSample ";
std::wstring newStr = boost::erase_all_regex_copy(oldStr, boost::regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+"));
```

Comment: I'm getting errors complaining about char_t and wchar_t conversion.  Perhaps this regex is implicitly assuming char_t instead of wchar_t? I put an L in front of the regex string, but it didn't like that either.

The beginning of the long long error message:
C:\boost_1_40_0\boost/regex/v4/perl_matcher_common.hpp(802) : warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'const wchar_t' to 'char', possible loss of data

Comment: Try changing boost::regex("etc.") to boost::regex<wchar_t>("etc."), perhaps? Then again, Eric up there has a good solution that probably won't give you the same trouble. :) (Also, I'd test this code myself, but I don't have boost installed on my dev machine...building/installing it now.)

Answer (score 0):

For those that are not so wise, here is ANSI and UNICODE functions based on @Éric Malenfant's answer:

```
std::string CleanString(const std::string& Input)
{
    std::string clean_string;
    std::locale loc;

    try {
        std::remove_copy_if(Input.begin(), Input.end(), std::back_inserter(clean_string),
            !(boost::bind(&std::isalnum<unsigned char>, _1, loc) || boost::bind(&std::isspace<unsigned char>, _1, loc)
        ));
    }
    catch (const std::bad_alloc& e) {
        std::cout << "Allocation failed: " << e.what() << '\n';
    }

    return clean_string;
}

std::wstring CleanString(const std::wstring& Input)
{
    std::wstring clean_string;
    std::locale loc;

    try {
        std::remove_copy_if(Input.begin(), Input.end(), std::back_inserter(clean_string),
            !(boost::bind(&std::isalnum<wchar_t>, _1, loc) ||
              boost::bind(&std::isspace<wchar_t>, _1, loc)
        ));
    } catch (const std::bad_alloc& e) {
        std::cout << "Allocation failed: " << e.what() << '\n';
    }
    return clean_string;
}
```

Online Demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/MFTwXV4ZCi9nsdlC

Full test code for Linux:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

// Note on Linux we use char and not unsigned char!
std::string CleanString(const std::string& Input)
{
    std::string clean_string;
    std::locale loc;

    try {
        std::remove_copy_if(Input.begin(), Input.end(), std::back_inserter(clean_string),
            !(boost::bind(&std::isalnum<char>, _1, loc) || boost::bind(&std::isspace<char>, _1, loc)
        ));
    }
    catch (const std::bad_alloc& e) {
        std::cout << "Allocation failed: " << e.what() << '\n';
    } 
    catch (...)
    {
    }

    return clean_string;
}

std::wstring CleanString(const std::wstring& Input)
{
    std::wstring clean_string;
    std::locale loc;

    try {
        std::remove_copy_if(Input.begin(), Input.end(), std::back_inserter(clean_string),
            !(boost::bind(&std::isalnum<wchar_t>, _1, loc) ||
              boost::bind(&std::isspace<wchar_t>, _1, loc)
        ));
    } 
    catch (const std::bad_alloc& e) {
        std::cout << "Allocation failed: " << e.what() << '\n';
    }
    catch (...)
    {
    }

    return clean_string;
}

int main()
{
    std::string test_1 = "Bla=bla =&*\n Sample Sample Sample !$%^&*@~";

    std::string new_test_1 = CleanString(test_1);

    if (!new_test_1.empty())
    {
        std::cout << "ANSI: " << new_test_1 << std::endl;
    }

    std::wstring test_uc_1 = L"!$%^&*@~ test &*";

    std::wstring new_test_uc_1 = CleanString(test_uc_1);

    if (!new_test_uc_1.empty())
    {
        std::wcout << L"UNICODE: " << new_test_uc_1 << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks to Éric Malenfant.